# SMS text messages on Ubuntu

Tags: indicator-message

I'm having a problem finding info on text messaging in Ubuntu. I've found some info from a few years ago, but nothing recent. Some  have mentioned KDE but I'm still not finding the info I want, or need. Some are even saying it's impossible ... in the 21st century??!!
I have an iPhone and want to be able to send, and receive messages to/from others, no matter what kind of phone they're using. TIA!

db

Comment: If you're talking about connecting your phone to your PC to use it from there, with an iPhone that is indeed next to impossible. KDE Connect exists but only works for Android phones.

Comment: @Sebastian:
So, it's not likely that I'm going to find a way to send and receive text messages? Or that I could only receive or send messages to an Android system.

Comment: With an iPhone, there is no way that I know of.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway!